# Ejecutar procedimiento desde C# Sql server y entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-8.0

Tengo un problema resulta que quiero ejecutar el procedimiento que esta en SQL y con estos datos asignarlos en un chart sin embargo no me funciona. (Estoy utilizando entity framework)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void reporteVentas()
        {

            using(RepuestosBD miBD = new RepuestosBD())
            {
                var result = miBD.SP_InformeVenta();
                foreach (var columnas in result)
                {
                    mes.Add(columnas.Column1);
                    montoTotal.Add(columnas.Column2);
                }



                //var consulta = from r in miBD.Venta
                //               group r by r.FechaVenta into g
                //               select new
                //               {
                //                   fecha = g.Key,
                //                   monto = g.Sum()
                //               };
            }

            chartVentasPorMes.Series[0].Points.AddXY(mes, montoTotal);
        }
```

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: El error de dice que el resultado de la consulta no devuelve un nombre de columna. ¿Probaste colocarle un alias?